# How to mock Amazon Route53 in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, mocking, amazon-route53

I am currently building an integration for Amazon Route53 in my Rails app. I would like to play with it while developing, but obviously I don't want to give valid AWS credentials or even trigger external requests.

I haven't seen any mock for Route53 out there, so my question is, how to mock this service so I can safely call it in development (and even testing) mode?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the integration with Route53? Is your Rail app doing DNS queries? Or is it modifying a zone records?

Comment: It's modifying zone records. It's just the external API calls that I need to restrict unless in production.

Answer (score 0):

In development (and test environments) use a [Private Hosted Zone](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html). In production use a standard public zone.

I also assume this is running on EC2 so be sure your [EC2 instance has a role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html), and that role has just enough permissions to modify the respective zone.

Comment: But that's exactly what I don't want to do, use the actual service in development/testing mode. It's slow, useless and it's definitely not a good practice.

Comment: All of those arguments seem a little weak. If you're not testing against the real service, you're not fully testing.  I disagree with this answer's suggestion of private hosted zones, since you can just as easily create additional hosted zones for exactly the same domain, in the same or different AWS accounts without impacting production because they're always assigned different authoritative nameservers.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot is right. I forgot about that. IF you are using multiple accounts you could create a zone for the same domain. Otherwise if you have only one AWS account private hosted zone would allow testing without impacts to production traffic.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment -- I left out a word. I intended to say you can create additional *public* hosted zones.  They're uniquely identified by the hosted-zone-id.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Now that I think of it, the multiple account thing *would work* but would add complexity in that you would need different credentials for the API between accounts. Using a private hosted zone would simplify that since it would all be in the same account